# What is the difference between TypeOf and InstanceOf in NUnit?

Tags: c#, nunit

In `NUnit`, what is the difference between `Is.TypeOf` and `Is.InstanceOf`?

In the following example, I've notice that they are both return true:

```
public class Foo
{
    public Boo GetBoo()
    {
        return new Boo();
    }
}

public class Boo { }
```

And the `NUnit` test method:

```
[Test]
public void GetBoo_WhenCalled_ReturnBoo
{
    var foo = new Foo();
    var result = foo.GetBoo();

    Assert.That(result, Is.TypeOf<Boo>()); //return true
    Assert.That(result, Is.InstanceOf<Boo>()); //return true
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [documentation](http://nunit.org/docs/2.6.4/typeConstraints.html) is kind of difficult to understand:

> `TypoOf` - tests that an object is an exact Type.
>
> `InstanceOf` - tests that an obect is an instance of a Type

It means that in contrast to `TypoOf`, `InstanceOf` will test also for derivites.

So, in the following example:

```
public class Foo
{
    public Boo GetBoo()
    {
        return new Woo();
    }
}

public class Woo : Boo { }
```

Test method:

```
[Test]
public void GetBoo_WhenCalled_ReturnBoo()
{
    var foo = new Foo();
    var result = foo.GetBoo();

    Assert.that(result, Is.TypeOf<Boo>()); // False ("Boo") 
    Assert.that(result, Is.InstanceOf<Boo>()); //True ("Boo" or "Woo")
}
```

`TypeOf` will return false cause it check if the result type is `Boo` only.
`InstanceOf` will return true cause it check if the result type is `Boo` or `Woo`.

Comment: Good answer, but your link to the docs is to legacy NUnit 2.4 documentation. Could you update?

Comment: I will try to update the link,  if you know the address be my guest

Comment: The new documentation is at https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/ExactTypeConstraint and https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/InstanceOfTypeConstraint I couldn't figure out how to fit it into your post without removing a lot of what you wrote.